# Arduino and GPRS read txt file from web

Tags: arduino, gprs

I'm using Arduino nano and Sim808 modem to read some data from internet.
To communicate with modem i'm using SeedStudio GPRS library. 
When I run the example program https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Seeeduino_GPRS/blob/master/example/GPRS_HTTP/GPRS_HTTP.ino
everything is ok and i get "hello world" message, so i tried to read txt file from my server http://instel.hr/proba.txt and instead of "hello!!!!" message I've got a lot of html tags and some text.
To read data from server I've made changes in the code in this 2 lines:
   I've replace this:

```
char http_cmd[] = "GET /media/uploads/mbed_official/hello.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
if(0 == gprs.connectTCP("mbed.org", 80)) {
```

With this:

```
char http_cmd[] = "GET proba.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
if(0 == gprs.connectTCP("instel.hr", 80)) {
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Luka

Comment: What HTML output did you get exactly? Most likely, its because your request isnt 'complete enough'. You need to add a Host header.

Comment: the problem is solved :)

 char http_cmd[] = "GET http://instel.hr/proba.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";

Comment: Nice. Like I said, you needed to specify a host. I doubt your server's IP address is unique to it; probably shared with others.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
char http_cmd[] = "GET proba.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
```

with

```
char http_cmd[] = "GET /proba.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
```

You missed "/" in your path.